# Run java classfile from terminal

Tags: command-line, java

I have a compiled java file `somefile.class`, and when i cd into the right folder and do: `java somefile` it works but when i call it from another folder: `java folder/somefile` it doesn't work, it gives me java exceptions, could you help me out?

Edit: I am working on a Mac if that matters..

Comment: Does your project use multiple class files? Do you still get the exception if you add the folder with the `somefile.class` to your path?

Comment: @LordLoh Do you mean to my environmental PATH variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `java folder/somefile` java tries to find a class `somefile` in the package `folder`, but your class isn't located in the package `folder`, it's just located in the path `folder`. You can adjust the search path for classes using the `-cp` option (meaning *classpath*).

For example having a class `YourClass` in the package `your.package`, this package is located in `/your/path` you can execute it from any location with:

```
java -cp /your/path your.package.YourClass
```

In your specific case you should run:

```
java -cp folder somefile
```

I hope it's clear enough ;-)